# Spring Boot Hibernate Ehcache entity caching implementation

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, ehcache

I need to query a DB table during application start and store table entries (entites) in ehcache. When ever request come for that row data (entity) need to fetch the data from cahce instead of going to DB.

I have implemented it using method level caching.But when it's not useful as whenever method param changes there is a hit going to DB.How to avoid it is there a example for entity level caching.

I am using Spring boot 1.2.4 ehcache and Spring Boot Data JPA.

Comment: you are referring to 2-3 distinct things that are hard to follow. Please present your question in code excerpts

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-load the data. Manually. Or using `Cache.getAll` with a loader-writer. Or `Cache.loadAll` from JSR 107.

One easy way is just to

```
List<MyEntity> entities = entityManager.getAll();
entities.forEach(e -> cache.put(e.getId(), e));
```

To use a loader-writer (see [ehcache doc](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.4/writers.html) it is

```
List<Long> entities = entityManager.getAllIds();
entities.forEach(id -> cache.get(id));
```

And finally, loadAll is just `cache.loadAll`.

Comment: How to get stored entity from cache any exaple

Comment: get them from cache or how to add them in the cache?

Comment: to get the entity from cache

Comment: But you said you are using method level caching. So it will hit the cache when accessing the method. Automatically through spring cache

Comment: I have done method level caching its working but I want to store entire table in cache during application startup and fetch the data during runtime.I need sample example for this.As if I use method level cahce whenever my method params changes it's firing query want to avoid it.

Comment: see new response